# Integrating custom Linux test project package with Alpine

Tags: linux, scripting, continuous-integration, alpine-linux

I have downloaded the **Linux Test Project** repository and compiled it. I now want to integrate it with the **Alpine's binary image** while compiling. A unix shell script that has Alpine specific commands will kick-in during compile time which adds these packages to the Alpine's binary. All the standard packages (like Python, Nginx and memcached) are getting integrated successfully by this script except **LTP**. The command used here is `apk add <package name>`. The same command doesn't work with the custom LTP's binary.

I tried n number of things like upgrading the apk package, supplying the entire LTP repository using `--repository` option, trying to manually generate an `APKBUILD.tar.gz`. Nothing works. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: ok. But maybe start from the beginnning. `now want to integrate it with the Alpine's binary image`  - what is a "alpine binary image" and what do you mean by "integrate it"? If you want to install apk package, you can use `apk add --allow-untrusted package.apk`, see [wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management#Add_a_local_Package). Now if you want to "create a repository for apk", short google search [shows](https://engineering.fundingcircle.com/blog/2015/04/28/create-alpine-linux-repository/) how it's done.

Comment: `integrated ... except LTP` -  do you mean "installed"? Just clone the [git](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp) repo or ltp and compile it yourself. But you did that and you want to "integrate it ... while compiling"? What does that mean? `supplying the entire LTP repository` - what does that mean? How did you "supply" it? Where is LTP repository? Please be more specific - don't say you "supplied" it, say "you edited a file that and that with those changes and issues 'this' command and 'that' command and it failed with 'this' error message". Be exact, specific.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I tried my best to explain. Let me elaborate a little more for you.
Alpine is a security oriented, light-weight Linux distribution and compiling it's source code will produce a .img root filesystem image. Since `ltp` is not a part of the alpine's .img image, I used the word **integration**. I want **ltp** (a non-standard alpine package) to be a part of the alpine's binary. **Installing** has the same meaning as that of **Integrating** as far as I understand.I tried this whole command `apk add --repository /so/and/so/path/to/ltp repo --allow-untrusted`.

Comment: `compiling it's source code` - alpine is a "distribution", it doesn't has sources to compile, it "distributes" sources of other packages. `.img root filesystem image` - please post the commands that resulted in the `img` file. Don't try to explain, code is worth more then 1000 words. Och, I see, then it's easy. That `img` file is most probably a cpio archive. Unpack it, add  ltp file to it, and pack it back. "installing"  means that the package manager `apk` knows about it. `apk` is smart - when you remove package, it will remove all unneeded dependencies (it keeps a tree of packages with...

Comment: ...dependencies of all installed packages). Now "integrating" could mean anything, including just copying files. `ltp a non-standard alpine package` - ltp is not a alpine package. Well, hm, I guess unless well you create an apk package with ltp binaries included.

Comment: I have already checked the both the links you gave me in your first comment, but to no avail. You have python packages and nginx packages in the form of .apk. These are standard packages which are **installed** at compile time using `apk add <pkg name>` command. But **ltp** does not get installed the usual way. Thats the reason I am trying to find help,

Comment: `at compile time` - there is no compilation here! `apk add` downloads files from a server and "install"s (ie. copies) them on your system. The "compilation" was done by someone else before the package was created - by the creator of the package on her/his computer. Cool, so let's concentrate on that `.img` file - how did you create it? Where is it from? You can create your own apk package with ltp - and, again, it's explained in the [wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package) how it's done.

Comment: There is a makefile written to produce the .img image and I do use `make` command to execute it. There is a compilation time as far as I understand that.
By **non-standard alpine package**, I meant that it was not a standard alpine package. Sorry about that. U are right.

Comment: `There is a makefile written` - where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200349/discussion-between-coding-ninja-and-kamil-cuk).